# Insert a new GUID to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: guid, visual-studio-2013

How to create GUIDs in Visual Studio 2013? I had an add in that worked well in VS2012 but it does not work in VS2013. I found this [Create GUID in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350028/insert-a-new-guid-to-visual-studio-2012) and this [How to convert VS2012 add ins to VS2013 Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn246938%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) but could not make it work (add ins are not my forte - I simply edit SQL scripts). Is there an easy way to get back this functionality?

Answer (score 49):

If you're using [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (highly recommended), you can create new GUIDs everywhere by typing `nguid` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that. But that's not what I am looking for. I want a VS 2013 Package (BTW these used to be known as 'add ins' in previous version of VS - but the VS2013 RC MSDN page says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn246938(v=vs.120).aspx) add ins are 'deprecated').

Answer (score 19):

Actually, uou can just use guidgen.exe which should get installed with VS.

Using menu TOOLS -> External Tools... add:

```
%Installation Path%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe
```

e.g.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\guidgen.exe
```

Give the title of ‘Create GUID’ and it is there just as it was in VS2010.

Answer (score 5):

The best tool / add-in for this is:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22795583-5cc9-4681-af8e-6084f3441655

Answer (score 3):

I was also wondering how I should do this. I saw the following example: [Inserting a Guid for VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350028/insert-a-new-guid-to-visual-studio-2012). For VS2013 you have to install the [SDK](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832352). Once you have done that you will see the template project items for packages and also for addins when you go to add a new project.

Despite the documentation saying that addins were deprecated in VS2013 they do appear to work (I am using VS2013 Ulitmate v 12.0.21005.1 REL). You can follow the instructions in the previous article.

I also created a package which was relatively straight forward too. Using How to: [Convert an Addin to a VS Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn246938.aspx) I was able to create the package.

As in the article I added the following using statements:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
```

I then changed the MenuItemCallback method to the following:

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DTE2 dte = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(DTE));

            if (dte.ActiveDocument != null)
            {
                TextSelection objSel = (EnvDTE.TextSelection)(dte.ActiveDocument.Selection);

                objSel.Insert(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            }
        }
```

After building the project I went to the bin\Debug folder and started the vsix file (GuidPackage.vsix in my case). This installed the package for use in the IDE.

I now have a menu item to insert guids into my code and am able to create a shortcut key stroke for it in the usual way.

Answer (score 2):

Just use PowerShell from VS Package Manage Console:

1. Switch to Package Manager Console (or you can open PowerShell cmd).
2. Execute `[guid]::NewGuid()`.

Result:

```
Guid                                
----                                
61dabfd8-9151-46f5-8d92-72306044d844
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this solution:

> _TUCHAR *guidStr = 0x00;
>
> GUID *pguid = 0x00;
>
> pguid = new GUID;
>
> CoCreateGuid(pguid);
>
> // Convert the GUID to a string UuidToString(pguid, &guidStr);
>
> delete pguid;

Answer (score 0):

One other tool that I came by was this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=florians.InsertGUIDCommand). Works pretty good

```
"Insert new GUID" (Shift+Alt+G): Inserts a new GUID at the current position.
"Insert last GUID" (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+G): Re-inserts the last new GUID at the current position.
```